# calculating min and max of user inputs

Tags: python-3.x, max, min

```
n = int(input("How many items?"))
for i in range(n-1):
    price = float(input("Price for the item? ")
    if price < ?:
        min_price = price
    if price > ?:
        max_price = price
    print("The least price is", min_price)
    print("The greatest price is", max_price)
```

Trying to find the min and max price of the user inputs.

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. Try to solve problem yourself before asking a question immediately after you've made some progress (getting the previous answers).

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input("How many items?"))
min_price = None
max_price = None
for i in range(n-1):
    price = float(input("Price for the item? "))
    if min_price is None:
        min_price = price
        max_price = price
    elif price < min_price:
        min_price = price
    elif price > max_price:
        max_price = price
    print("The least price is", min_price)
    print("The greatest price is", max_price)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You seem to be missing a parenthesis in line 5. Also, your solution is nice and clean, if maybe a bit verbose :)

Comment: I didn't know that `Null` is a keyword in Python

Answer (score 0):

While Paul Becotte's answer may work well, here is a smaller implementation, using python's builtin `min` and `max` functions. To initialize the values, you can parse `inf` (infinity), so the min_price initial value will always be bigger than the first one you enter...

```
min_price = float("inf")
max_price = float("-inf")

for i in range(n-1):
    price = float(intput("Price for the item? "))
    min_price = min(min_price, price)
    max_price = max(max_price, price)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in different method, give the min and max variables value of `float('inf')` or `None` or in third way get the variable from the user and put it in min and max

```
n=input('how many items?')
min=float('+inf')
max=float('-inf')
for i in range(n):
    price=input ('price for the item?')
    if price<min:
            min=price
    if price>max:
            max=price
print("the minimum is ",min)
print("the maximum is ",max)
```

another method:

```
n=input('how many items?')
min=None
max=None
for i in range(n):
    price=input ('price for the item?')
    if min is None:
        min=price;
        max=price;
    elif price<min:
        min=price
    elif price>max:
        max=price
print("the minimum is ",min)
print("the maximum is ",max)
```

another method:

```
n=input('how many items?')
price=input ('price for the item?')
min=max=price;
for i in range(n-1):
    price=input ('price for the item?')
    if price<min:
         min=price
    if price>max:
         max=price
print("the minimum is ",min)
print("the maximum is ",max)
```

also notice that when you put range(n-1) the item that would be asked is less than the number of items that user want to enter. so only in case that you get price out of loop the range is (n-1), in all other cases the range is (n)